# Error "Scanner(String) is undefined for the type Scanner"

Tags: java

So my aim is to be able to add something to the ArrayList through user input. I don't understand why line 5 of the code is giving me the error "Scanner(String) is undefined for the type Scanner". Thanks to anyone that attempted to help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Grocery> cart = new ArrayList<Grocery>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What grocery do you want to put in your cart??");
    Grocery.add(sc.Scanner(System.in.toString()));
```

new class

```
public Grocery(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}
```

Comment: What is `sc.Scanner`? You need `new Scanner`. Typo. And, `System.in.toString()`? What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner(String)` is a valid constructor, so that can't be your compile-time error. You should have `cart.add(new Grocery(sc.nextLine()))` for line 5.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
ArrayList<Grocery> cart = new ArrayList<Grocery>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What grocery do you want to put in your cart??");
String grocery =sc.nextLine();
Grocery.add(grocery);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you did not specify what type of input to read from the user because there are many types for example int or float etc.. ,Try this one :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList<Grocery> cart = new ArrayList<Grocery>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What grocery do you want to put in your cart??");
String str = sc.nextLine(); // **you forgot this step**
Grocery.add(str);
```

Comment: It returns String ,it is just a habit i used to do it not more :D

Comment: And i remove it now :D